# switch d3 chart on selection of dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

Hi I'm implementing the D3.js chart in my module.I need that on the basis of my dropdown selection my chart type will update accordingly.

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vaqa6s73/1/)

I have `sample.json` file to retrieve data from `json`.

```
{
    "sample2": [{
        "time": 1387212120,
        "open": 368,
        "close": 275,
        "high": 380,
        "low": 158
    }, {
        "time": 1387212130,
        "open": 330,
        "close": 350,
        "high": 389,
        "low": 310
    }, {
        "time": 1387212140,
        "open": 213,
        "close": 253,
        "high": 289,
        "low": 213
    }, {
        "time": 1387212150,
        "open": 180,
        "close": 150,
        "high": 189,
        "low": 110
    }, {
        "time": 1387212160,
        "open": 310,
        "close": 350,
        "high": 389,
        "low": 310
    }]
}
```

Comment: {"sample2": [ {"time": 1387212120, "open": 368, "close": 275, "high": 380, "low": 158}, {"time": 1387212130, "open": 330, "close": 350, "high": 389, "low": 310}, {"time": 1387212140, "open": 213, "close": 253, "high": 289, "low": 213}, {"time": 1387212150, "open": 180, "close": 150, "high": 189, "low": 110}, {"time": 1387212160, "open": 310, "close": 350, "high": 389, "low": 310} ]}

Comment: you chart are updating find the [fiddler](http://jsfiddle.net/vaqa6s73/1/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Line is the default chart selected in your demo. So you should kept that option selected by default in the drop down also (For now, I have put 'line' as the first option in the code snippet and will be selected by default). Also note that the data bonded to the pie chart paths was not correct. You should bind data as shown below and since pie chart need multiple paths to be drawn, you should use `selectAll` and `enter` method for this.

```
var container = canvas.selectAll(".arc")
      .data(pie(sample2))
      .enter().append("path")
```

instead of

```
 canvas.append("path")
       .datum(sample2);
```

And hide/show the x and y axes, when switching between pie chart and other charts.

```js
// loading sample.json
var sample2 = {
  "sample2": [{
    "time": 1387212120,
    "open": 368,
    "close": 275,
    "high": 380,
    "low": 158
  }, {
    "time": 1387212130,
    "open": 330,
    "close": 350,
    "high": 389,
    "low": 310
  }, {
    "time": 1387212140,
    "open": 213,
    "close": 253,
    "high": 289,
    "low": 213
  }, {
    "time": 1387212150,
    "open": 180,
    "close": 150,
    "high": 189,
    "low": 110
  }, {
    "time": 1387212160,
    "open": 310,
    "close": 350,
    "high": 389,
    "low": 310
  }]
};

sample2 = sample2.sample2
  // date manipulation to format UTC to js Date obj
sample2.forEach(function(d) {
  d.time = new Date(d.time * 1000);
});

// helpers and constants
var margin = {
  "top": 50,
  "right": 100,
  "bottom": 56,
  "left": 50
};
var width = 930 - margin.right - margin.left;
var height = 582 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
var radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2;
var timeFormat = d3.time.format("%c");
var X = width / sample2.length * 0.25;

// find data range
var xDomain = d3.extent(sample2, function(d, i) {
  return d.time;
});
var yMin = d3.min(sample2, function(d) {
  return Math.min(d.low);
});
var yMax = d3.max(sample2, function(d) {
  return Math.max(d.high);
});

// scales, add 10pc padding to x-domain
var xScale = d3.time.scale()
  .domain(xDomain);

var arc = d3.svg.arc()
  .innerRadius(radius - 100)
  .outerRadius(radius - 20);


xScale.domain([-0.1, 1.1].map(xScale.invert))
  .range([margin.left, width - margin.right]);

var yScale = d3.scale.linear()
  .domain([yMin, yMax])
  .range([height - margin.top, margin.bottom]);

// set up axes
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
  .scale(xScale)
  .orient("bottom")
  .ticks(10)
  .tickPadding(10);
// .tickFormat(timeFormat)

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
  .scale(yScale)
  .orient("right")
  .tickValues(yScale.domain());

// set up chart types
var area = d3.svg.area()
  .x(function(d) {
    return xScale(d.time);
  })
  .y0(height - margin.bottom)
  .y1(function(d) {
    return yScale(d.close);
  });

var line = d3.svg.line().interpolate("monotone")
  .x(function(d) {
    return xScale(d.time);
  })
  .y(function(d) {
    return yScale(d.close);
  });

var pie = d3.layout.pie()
  .value(function(d) {
    return d.time;
  })
  .sort(null);

// create svg container and offset
var canvas = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr({
    "width": width,
    "height": height
  })
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.top / 2 + "," + margin.left / 2 + ")");

var color = d3.scale.category20();
// gridsk
canvas.append("svg:rect")
  .attr({
    "width": width - margin.right - margin.left,
    "height": height - margin.bottom - margin.top,
    "class": "plot",
    "transform": "translate(" + margin.top + "," + margin.bottom + ")"
  });

// chart options by type
var chartDraw = {

  candle: function() {

    canvas.selectAll("line.candle")
      .data(sample2)
      .enter()
      .append("svg:line")
      .attr({
        "class": "candle alt-view",
        "x1": function(d, i) {
          return xScale(d.time) - X * 0.5;
        },
        "x2": function(d, i) {
          return xScale(d.time) - X * 0.5;
        },
        "y1": function(d, i) {
          return yScale(d.high);
        },
        "y2": function(d, i) {
          return yScale(d.low);
        },
        "stroke": "black"
      });

    canvas.selectAll("rect.candle")
      .data(sample2)
      .enter()
      .append("svg:rect")
      .attr({
        "class": "candle alt-view",
        "width": function(d) {
          return X
        },
        "x": function(d, i) {
          return xScale(d.time) - X;
        },
        "y": function(d, i) {
          return yScale(Math.max(d.open, d.close));
        },
        "height": function(d, i) {
          return yScale(Math.min(d.open, d.close)) - yScale(Math.max(d.open, d.close));
        },
        "fill": function(d) {
          return d.open > d.close ? "#dc432c" : "#0CD1AA"
        },
        "stroke": "gray"
      });

  },

  line: function() {

    canvas.append("path")
      .datum(sample2)
      .attr("class", "line alt-view")
      .attr("d", line);
  },

  pie: function() {
    var container = canvas.selectAll(".arc")
      .data(pie(sample2))
      .enter().append("path")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")")
      .attr("class", "pie alt-view")
      .attr("fill", function(d, i) {
        return color(i);
      })
      .attr("d", arc)
      .each(function(d) {
        this._current = d;
      });
  },

  area: function() {

    canvas.append("path")
      .datum(sample2)
      .attr("class", "area alt-view")
      .attr("d", area);
  }
};


// draw axes
canvas.append('g').classed("axis", true).call(xAxis)
  .attr('transform', 'translate(0, ' + (height - margin.bottom) + ')');
canvas.append('g').classed("axis", true).call(yAxis)
  .attr('transform', 'translate(' + (width - margin.right) + ', 0)');

// drop down menu
var chartOptions = ["line", "candle", "area", "pie"];
var dropdown = d3.select("body").append("foreignObject")
  .attr({
    "height": 100,
    "width": 300,
    "transform": "translate(" + margin.left * 1.3 + "," + margin.top * 0.7 + ")"
  })
  .append("xhtml:select")
  .on("change", function() {

    d3.selectAll(".alt-view").remove();

    selected = this.value;

    if (selected == "line") {
      canvas.selectAll(".axis").style("display", "block");
      canvas.select(".plot").style("display", "block");
      chartDraw.line();
    } else if (selected == "area") {
      canvas.selectAll(".axis").style("display", "block");
      canvas.select(".plot").style("display", "block");
      chartDraw.area();
    } else if (selected == "candle") {
      canvas.selectAll(".axis").style("display", "block");
      canvas.select(".plot").style("display", "block");
      chartDraw.candle();
    } else if (selected == "pie") {
      canvas.selectAll(".axis").style("display", "none");
      canvas.select(".plot").style("display", "none");
      chartDraw.pie();
    }

  })
  .attr("id", "drop-down")
  .selectAll("option")
  .data(chartOptions)
  .enter()
  .append("option")
  .text(function(d) {
    return d;
  })
  .attr("value", function(d) {
    return d;
  });


// default chart
chartDraw.line();
```

```css
.line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #0CD1AA;
  stroke-width: 3px;
}
.area {
  fill: #0cd1aa;
  stroke: #dc432c;
  stroke-width 0.5;
}
.plot {
  fill: lightblue;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script src="inlet.js"></script>
<link src="style.css" />

<body></body>
```

Comment: Can anyone help me out to move Y-axis from right side to left and data will be shown accordingly.